# Coworkers continually disrespect the workplace, boss, and customers

Tags: professionalism, communication, work-environment, colleagues, unprofessional-behavior

To start, I'd like to highlight that, though the youngest team member, I've been in this gas station cashier job for over two years, second only to the boss in time working here. My boss always taught me to follow the rules and why, and I've naturally always been more of a rule follower than a rule breaker (if only to cover my own butt). Everyone else currently working here has been here 6 months or less.

We recently had a meeting to discuss any problems we have in our workplace, the boss specifically outlined that there was to be no naming or pointing of fingers at the beginning. Regardless of that, the first employee to have something to say immediately named the person they had a problem with. Then it was my turn to state my problems immediately after, I tried to set an example by keeping my problems vague and refusing to name names. My problem was that people would consistently break the rule of keeping our bags in the back room and stated the reason being as trip and fall risk, if anything is missing and your bag is up front you will be suspected, and being written up. The next to speak targeted me, she worked third shift and was the most adamant in her disrespect of the workplace. She spoke of how her bag was moved "thrown" and had ended up on its side, which I had really pushed with no care for the item that wasn't meant to be there because it was in my way of quickly obtaining a product for my customer. She complained that I was disrespectful toward her and that she was tired of it. The boss allowed me to respond and I apologized for moving her bag, but I didn't throw it, and it wouldn't have been a problem if she followed the rules. I then outlined an attitude issue which anyone I've ever seen promoted (who never lasted long for these reasons) acted superior and often has shown disrespect and pure unadulterated meanness towards their other coworkers. The boss sides with me that the rules of the corporation are to be followed and we are to treat one another with professionalism, this is a job, not a school full of teens.

I have, in the past attempted to casually and professionally remind my coworkers of the rules, or ask them calmly not to move stuff around too much because items that are needed become impossible to find. I tried this many times, and each was met with condescension and dismissal, the boss has done the same in a much more stern fashion, as her station allows, and received the same disrespect. So, I simply stopped asking, I would move their belongings out of my way gently as I needed, and I would (perhaps a bit passive-aggressively) find and relocate items to their proper places as soon as I was clocked in and at my register. This upset my coworkers because they had now had perceived disrespect aimed at them.

I genuinely only said anything because I care that they don't lose their jobs and I've seen people fired for less in my time here. And now, I feel a righteous fury for my boss's sake. She's 66, she's an incredible woman and boss, and she's not in the best of health due to her age. The more stress she receives from this insubordination and childish drama, the more likely it is that she'll be back in the hospital from having mini strokes multiple times a day (a little over a year ago, they kept her for a week of observation) and the more likely that she won't come out alive this time...

After the meeting one coworker threatened the boss with calling HR, and no one has really changed their behavior except for it getting worse. How am I supposed to deal with a job I once loved and customers leaving the store due to the atmosphere, being turned into a place I hate by unprofessional and selfish "Karens" being my coworkers?

Comment: Have not read this question - too long.  But could you narrow down the problem a little into a few paragraphs?

Comment: “Seh spoke of how her bag was moved "thrown" and had ended up on its side, which I had really pushed with no care for the item that wasn't meant to be there because it was in my way of quickly obtaining a product for my customer.” - You should have show some more respect for your coworkers.  Hopefully, you didn’t literally say this, at the meeting.  Calling these coworkers Karens is also disrespectful.

Answer (score 8):

Your boss is the boss but it sounds like your boss is not being a boss.  If the boss tells the subordinate to do something, and the subordinate disrespects the boss, then the boss fires the subordinate.  If the boss fails to fire the subordinate, then the subordinate will continue to disrespect the boss until the boss does fire the subordinate.  That's how it works.  Furthermore, if the boss fails to discipline the subordinate when the subordinate directly disrespects the boss herself, what makes you think that the boss will do anything at all when the subordinate disrespects not-the-boss, i.e. you?  To be honest I'm somewhat surprised that this organization is functional at all.

As  for what you should do: You can't actually do  more than you're already doing.  Ask nicely for the other people to stop doing the things you don't like.  If they give you an argument, well, that's it.  You're not going to get (meaningful) support from your boss, so that's just it.   Sorry.

Comment: This answer is correct, OP is currently picking up slack from the boss not enforcing her own rules, but OP is coming under fire as they don't have the natural armor that a boss does (i.e. authority). As much as OP's position is understandable, it's something that a lot of people inherently mock (there are _many_ examples in common media), which in turn leads to frustration and friction between the employees.

Comment: This answers suggests the only way to manage a team is to threaten to fire everyone? Surely there are other ways.

Comment: @Stef Well it's certainly not to never fire anyone, no matter what they do or how disrespectful or contrary they are, which is what this boss seems to be doing.  Firing someone for gross disrespect (which seems to be happening here) must certainly be something that's on the table.  Unless you believe that such actions are viable, in which case I encourage you, in your next office meeting, to call your boss an asshole in front of everyone and see how that goes for you.

Comment: @Ertai87 I don't follow your reasoning. How did you go from "a coworker left their bag in the wrong place" to "I encourage you to call your boss an asshole during the next office meeting"?

Comment: @Stef Please reread the OP, specifically this part: "I tried this many times, and each was met with condescension and dismissal, the boss has done the same in a much more stern fashion, as her station allows, and received the same disrespect".  If you, as a subordinate, act towards your boss with "condescension and dismissal", how do you think your boss would react?

Answer (score 5):

> So, I simply stopped asking, I would move their belongings out of my way gently as I needed

This points to a deeper problem. If there are no safe and easy to access lockers/cages/shelves for your co-workers to put their belongings into/onto, then I think that's a problem.

I don't care if you have to remove products from a shelf to make room but you need to find a creative solution to this problem.

And yes, if HR gets contacted, they're going to tell you to stop touching your co-worker's stuff (without asking for permission first) even if it happens to be on the floor. So stop doing that, it's not a winning strategy. Even if your co-workers are wrong, two wrongs don't make a right.

> She's 66, she's an incredible woman and boss, and she's not in the
> best of health due to her age.

I'm sorry, but it's not your job or your responsibility to protect her. The worst part is that you do not have the authority to protect her either.

If she can't get the respect of her subordinates, then it may be time for her to retire, or to find a different job where being a hardass isn't a requirement.

> How am I supposed to deal with a job I once loved and customers leaving the store due to the atmosphere

Come on. It's a gas station. 99% of your customers choose your gas station for the convenience or for the price of gas, not for its atmosphere.

You've been there two years already. I say you've outgrown the place. Look for a new employer, preferably a place where you get paid more and where you work with a better class of coworkers.

> being turned into a place I hate by unprofessional and selfish "Karens" being my coworkers?

Don't use the term "Karen" here. It doesn't help and it doesn't fit. Technically, they're not the ones trying to enforce the rules, you're the one who's trying to do that.

So if anyone is the "Karen", it's probably you. And I say this in the nicest way. If I were in your place, I would have probably been the "Karen" as well.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing that this is first and foremost a _safety issue_ (OP describes it as "trip and fall risk"). The boss should care that it is a safety issue and should care about adhering to the regulations established by corporate for insurance and/or government compliance. Framing the problem as "people keep breaking the rules" comes across as petty, framing it as "people's actions are creating a safety hazard" comes across as responsible.

Comment: @B.Ithica, Actually, I'm placing the blame on the business itself, not on people's actions. If this is indeed a recurring problem, then I think the underlying system needs to be changed. When employees don't have their own space for themselves, it creates problems for the business itself. For instance, when you don't give employees a place to eat their lunch in a factory, you'll find employees eating their lunch anywhere on the factory floor, which is not ideal for sanitation or quality control, or even rodent control.

Comment: Yes -- the thing is, "the business itself" can't do anything. OP did the right thing calling out a safety issue. The onus is then on the manager to provide a safe environment for the workers, and corporate surely has a policy on this that they can consult. If that's not something they're interested in doing -- it's a bit hard to tell but it sounds like they're more interested in indulging the employees' petty squabbling -- then that's a bad sign that goes well beyond all the other issues laid out in this question, imo.

Answer (score 4):

Respect is a two-way street. If your coworkers don't feel respected, they will not respect you, your boss or the workplace.

To respect your coworkers you need to listen to their concerns. If they aren't following the rules, why aren't they? Maybe it is really inconvenient for them to keep their bag in the back room. Is there a solution that will solve the problem for both parties?

Answer (score 3):

#### Try to get promoted.

If you're the only employee who respects the boss and follows the rules, you're probably the only employee with a chance for promotion. It sounds like your current boss is likely moving towards retirement; perhaps you could speak with her about taking on additional duties and moving up in the corporate structure, in preparation for her eventual departure.

Then, once you've become the new boss, you'll be able to deal with your new subordinates in an appropriate fashion when they show you disrespect and break the rules.

Answer (score 1):

> I care that they don't lose their jobs...

Stop doing that.

> I've seen people fired for less in my time here.

OK, so your boss *will* fire people, and apparently for lesser infractions, so I have to assume that you're correct and by moving their bags you've been protecting their jobs.

You have to stop doing that. It's not your job to protect *their* jobs and if they're that miserable to work with then you shouldn't want to.

Let your boss actually see these infractions so that your co-workers will get disciplined for them. That is the only thing that is going to change their behavior. And since you don't have the authority to do that yourself then you need to let your boss do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your boss is not enforcing the rules but what happens on most jobs is that each individual is always held to the standard they set for themselves, no matter what. So if you set the standard of following 100% of the rules, now if you break even 1 rule you'd like get into trouble while the person who only follows 20% of the rules won't get into trouble. If your boss won't enforce the rules people are breaking then there's nothing you can do since you aren't in management. May be time to find another job.